# How do I fill my DataGrid with my C# list containing my XML Data that was parsed from a XML Node Reader?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, wpf, datagrid

I have data in my XML file that i collected by reading my XML file and storing my data based on each node into an object.

I want to fill my DataGrid with the data from my List (jobList), but I am not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Dynamically building table and adding data.
Building the XML manually.

```
    public partial class amgrid : Window
    {
        public static Configuration AppSettings { get; set; }
        JobList job = new JobList();

        public amgrid()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            string docPath = @"C:\Users\contract_lshamoon\Desktop\arm\arm\arm\xmldb.xml";
            doc.Load(docPath);
            XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
            XmlNodeList elemList = root.GetElementsByTagName("Jobs");
            findAllNodes(root);
            doc.Save(@"C:\Users\contract_lshamoon\Desktop\arm\arm\arm\xmldb.xml");
            DG.DataContext = job;

        }

        int index = 0;
        public void findAllNodes(XmlNode node)
        {
            index++;
            foreach (XmlNode n in node)
                findAllNodes(n);

            if (node.Name == "Job")
            {
                job.Job = index.ToString();
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("job.Job" + " : " + index + " : " + job.Job);
            }
            if (node.Name == "JobDate")
            {
                job.JobDate = node.InnerText;
                Console.WriteLine("Job.JobDate" + " : " + job.JobDate);
            }
            if (node.Name == "File")
            {
                job.File = node.InnerText;
                Console.WriteLine("Job.File" + " : " + job.File);
            }
            if (node.Name == "FilePath")
            {
                job.FilePath = node.InnerText;
                Console.WriteLine("Job.FilePath" + " : " + job.FilePath);
            }
            if (node.Name == "Extension")
            {
                job.Extension = node.InnerText;
                Console.WriteLine("Job.Extension" + " : " + job.Extension);
            }
            if (node.Name == "Age")
            {
                job.Age = node.InnerText;
                Console.WriteLine("Job.Age" + " : " + job.Age);
            }
            if (node.Name == "JobComment")
            {
                job.JobComment = node.InnerText;
                Console.WriteLine("Job.JobComment" + " : " + job.JobComment);
            }
        }

        private List<JobList> LoadCollectionData()
        {
            List<JobList> jobList = new List<JobList>();

            jobList.Add(new JobList()
            {
                Job = job.Job,
                JobDate = job.JobDate,
                FilePath = job.FilePath,
                Extension = job.Extension,
                Age = job.Age,
                JobComment = job.JobComment
            });

            return jobList;
        }
    }

    public class JobList
    {
        [XmlAttribute("JobId")]
        public string Job { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("JobDate")]
        public string JobDate { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("File")]
        public string File { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("FilePath")]
        public string FilePath { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("Extension")]
        public string Extension { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("Age")]
        public string Age { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("JobComment")]
        public string JobComment { get; set; }
    }
```

```
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="DG" ItemsSource="{Binding jobList}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="JobCol" Binding="{Binding Job}" Header="Job"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="JobDateCol" Binding="{Binding JobDate}" Header="Date"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="FilePathCol" Binding="{Binding FilePath}" Header="Path"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="ExtensionCol" Binding="{Binding Extension}" Header="Extension"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="AgeCol" Binding="{Binding Age}" Header="Age"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="JobCommentCol" Binding="{Binding JobComment}" Header="Comment"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>

        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
```

I just want every row to have each list item displayed.

Comment: You never fill the job list with anything.

Comment: I am providing a blank example...

Comment: I have tried: DG.Items.Add(jobs);
But that fills every row with the same job over and over

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public class JobList
    {
        [XmlElement("Job")]
        public string Job { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("JobDate")]
        public string JobDate { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("File")]
        public string File { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("FilePath")]
        public string FilePath { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("Extension")]
        public string Extension { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("Age")]
        public string c { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("JobComment")]
        public string JobComment { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class amgrid : Window
    {
        public amgrid()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            string docPath = @"C:\Users\contract_lshamoon\Desktop\arm\arm\arm\xmldb.xml";
            doc.Load(docPath);
            XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
            XmlNodeList elemList = root.GetElementsByTagName("Jobs");
            findAllNodes(root);
            doc.Save(@"C:\Users\contract_lshamoon\Desktop\arm\arm\arm\xmldb.xml");
        }

        public void findAllNodes(XmlNode node)
        {
            foreach (XmlNode n in node)
            {
                JobList jobs = new JobList();

                string job = n.Attributes["JobId"].Value;
                string date = n.FirstChild.InnerText;
                string file = n.FirstChild.NextSibling.InnerText;
                string path = n.FirstChild.NextSibling.NextSibling.InnerText;
                string extension = n.FirstChild.NextSibling.NextSibling.NextSibling.InnerText;
                string age = n.FirstChild.NextSibling.NextSibling.NextSibling.NextSibling.InnerText;
                string comment = n.FirstChild.NextSibling.NextSibling.NextSibling.NextSibling.NextSibling.InnerText;

                jobs.Job = job;
                jobs.JobDate = date;
                jobs.File = file;
                jobs.FilePath = path;
                jobs.Extension = extension;
                jobs.c = age;
                jobs.JobComment = comment;

                DG.DataContext = jobs;
                DG.Items.Add(jobs);
            }
        }
    }
```

```
        <DataGrid x:Name="DG">
            <DataGrid.DataContext>
                <local:JobList/>
            </DataGrid.DataContext>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="JobCol" Binding="{Binding Job}" Header="Job"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="JobDateCol" Binding="{Binding JobDate}" Header="Date"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="FilePathCol" Binding="{Binding FilePath}" Header="Path"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="ExtensionCol" Binding="{Binding Extension}" Header="Extension"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="AgeCol" Binding="{Binding Age}" Header="Age"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="JobCommentCol" Binding="{Binding JobComment}" Header="Comment"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>

        </DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 1):

The type of `job`, `JobList`, is not a list as its type implies.  It contains only a single job's properties.  You have only one instance of that class and it's assigned to `job`.  Every time you encounter a node, you're modifying that instance's properties.

When you tried `DB.Items.Add(job);`, you were adding the same instance to the grid's list of items, so naturally, it would show that item N times.  Moreover it would be the cumulative result of the values you assigned to those properties (i.e. the last value written to each property).

If I'm understanding your structure correctly (which is difficult because you haven't shown a sample of the XML), you're navigating XML nodes and treating all node types equally (including elements and attributes).  If, for example, you have just two elements, where one element has only the `JobDate` attribute and the other element has only the `FilePath` attribute, `job` will ultimately have both properties assigned and both rows will show those two values.  It will not show one row with one value and another row with the other value because you have no instances that have been placed into those states.

Another issue is that you're missing the idea that an element should map to a `JobList` instance and the attributes should map to that instance's properties.  `findAllNodes` is (arguably) a good algorithm for traversing the XML nodes, but without treating the node types differently, it's not doing what you want for the purpose of loading the data.  Specifically, at some node types, you need to instantiate a `JobList` and in others, you need to assign values to its properties.  XML serialization is a better option here because it will do all of that for you.  You even have the attributes for it on the properties, so go right ahead and use it.

You also have a method called `LoadCollectionData` but you never call it (or at least you haven't shown that you're calling it anywhere).  That method *does* return a list of items but it's adding to it the only instance of `JobList` you've ever created, the one in your `job` field.

If you eliminate the `job` field (the line that reads `JobList job = new JobList();`), you'll start getting errors where you were using that one instance.  That will break your code but, Hopefully, that will also show you where you should be creating a new instances (or accepting instances as parameters).

Some additional review notes:

- You're saving the XML document back to disk without modifying it.  You can safely remove the call to `doc.Save`.
- Loading data in the constructor is probably not a good idea.  Now, I'm no WPF expert (and I don't even play one on TV) but you should look for a "load" event to handle or something like that.  Eventually, you'll want to use `async` so your UI can be responsive while loading.
- As a general rule, don't declare a variable until you need it.  When you declare a variable and let it "rot" until you use it, you allow yourself to make mistakes in the execution sequence, which can lead to things like `NullReferenceException`s when you forget that you haven't initialized it yet.  And don't promote it to a field until you know it has to be a field.

As answers go, that's about as much as I can say because the code you provided is a bit circuitous and your intent is not entirely clear.  I wish you luck in applying the above information.

Comment: Thank you! This is awesome! I will try this out!
Still a little new to C#!